# TTEST across 86 different groups without taking mean using EXCEL(only)

Tags: excel

I have a data set based on 86 different groups (divided into subgroups i.e. 1,1,1 2,2,2 etc) and each group has 1 value on which I need to perform a TTEST. My data is arranged in 2 columns. For example, column A for groups and column B for values. I have 10 rows for group 1 and 12 for group 2 and so on. 
I am struggling with INDEX & TTEST formula to make something that I could drag and populate automatically.
I know python, Rstudio would make my life easier but I am limited to EXCEL for this problem.

Thanks!